# Own _.map() implement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Trying to understand this:**

```
const _ = {};
_.map = function(list, callback){
    var storage = [];
    for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        storage.push(callback(list[i], i, list));
    }
    return storage;
}

_.map([1,2,3], function(val){return val+1;})
```

**Why does the callback require 3 args, when we clearly need only one?**

```
_.map = function(list, callback){
    var storage = [];
    for(let i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        storage.push(callback(list[i])); //****** This works too!
    }
    return storage;
}

_.map([1,2,3], function(val){return val+1;})
```

Context: Doing a course on Frontend Masters, where they implemented it like the first version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Array#map method can have up to 3 parameters for its callback.
mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
map((element) => { ... })
map((element, index) => { ... })
map((element, index, array) => { ... })
```

since you are not using the other two params `index, array` they would be undefined.

run the below code for both declarations to understand better.

```js
_.map([1,2,3], function(val,index,arr){
  console.log(val)
  console.log(index)
  console.log(arr)
})
```

Comment: Interesting, so to extend the functionality, you would want to have index as well. Is there an example where we would use array?

Answer (score 0):

It's because if you lookup at the current definition of the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the callback function can receive up to three argument as you can see bellow.

```
map(function callbackFn(element) { ... })
map(function callbackFn(element, index) { ... })
map(function callbackFn(element, index, array){ ... })
map(function callbackFn(element, index, array) { ... }, thisArg)
```

Apart from the item at the given index on the array which the map function is call, you can receive the index and the array it self.

**callbackFn**

Function that is called for every element of arr. Each time callbackFn executes, the returned value is added to newArray.

The callbackFn function accepts the following arguments:

- element

  ```
   The current element being processed in the array.
  ```
- index **Optional**

  ```
   The index of the current element being processed in the array.
  ```
- array **Optional**

  ```
   The array map was called upon.
  ```
- thisArg **Optional**

  Value to use as this when executing callbackFn.